# For of to forEach -> lambda expression

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, lambda, foreach

I have a "for of" on my java code and Im trying to convert to a "for each" with a lambda expression.

```
for (Bicycle element : bicycleList) {
    txtOutput.append("Model:" + element.getModel() + "\n"); 
}
```

I have tried to do this:

```
bicycleList.forEach(txtOutput.append -> ("Model:" + bicycle.getModel() + "\n"));
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would suggest `reduce` (might need to `map`). Have a look at the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax

Answer (score 0):

bicycleList.forEach(element -> txtOutput.append ("Model:" + element.getModel() + "\n"));

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use streams as :

```
String txtOutput = bicycleList.stream()
        .map(element -> "Model:" + element.getModel() + "\n")
        .collect(Collectors.joining("", "", ""));
```